# How to create a list of vectors with specific format?

Tags: r, arrays, list

I'm trying to create a list that looks like `[1, 1] [1, 2] [1, 3], [2, 1] [2, 2] [2, 3], [3, 1] [3, 2] [3, 3]`. I mean the list contains all vectors `c(i, j)` for `i` from 1 to 3, and for `j` from 1 to 3. I'm unable to do so. I can only generate an array that contains numbers.

```
my.array <- array(NA, dim = c(3, 3))
for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    my.array[i, j] <- 5
  }
}
```

Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for - perhaps this?

```r
matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3), 1, 
             function(x) paste0("[", paste(x, collapse = ", "), "]")), nrow = 3)
#>       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#> [1,] "[1, 1]" "[1, 2]" "[1, 3]"
#> [2,] "[2, 1]" "[2, 2]" "[2, 3]"
#> [3,] "[3, 1]" "[3, 2]" "[3, 3]"
```

Or this?

```r
lapply(split(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3), 1:9), function(x) as.vector(unlist(x)))
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 1
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 2 1
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 3 1
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $`5`
#> [1] 2 2
#> 
#> $`6`
#> [1] 3 2
#> 
#> $`7`
#> [1] 1 3
#> 
#> $`8`
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> $`9`
#> [1] 3 3
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I meant the list contains all the vectors `c(i, j)`. I would like to apply `parallel::clusterApply` to that list. The function `f` I use in parallel computing take the first and second coordinate of each vector `c(i, j)` as input.

Comment: When I extract the first element of the list, it also returns the symbol `$`.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or your intention. https://imgur.com/UM4ZVyQ

Comment: @LAD that's because it is a list, as requested. try double brackets to get the unlisted contents `[[1]]`